# How to pass 'mHeaders' in loadData method of JSONModel?

Tags: sapui5, jsonmodel

I need to know how to pass authorization values in `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` -> `loadData()` method

[API reference](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData)
I am trying to execute this -

```
var uri = "https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/GWDEMO/ProductCollection?$format=json";
var ojsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var oHeaders = {
    "Authorization": {
        "Basic": btoa('P1940678860' + 'rahul123')
    }
};
ojsonModel.loadData(uri, null, true, "GET", null, false, oHeaders);
console.log(ojsonModel);
```

I am getting error **401 (Unauthorized)**

Comment: Added in question itself

Comment: Does your custom header show in the network tab of your dev tools?

Comment: It is showing this - `GET /https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/GWDEMO/ProductCollection?$format=json&_=1464713454801 HTTP/1.1
Host: cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://run.plnkr.co
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
Authorization: [object Object]
Referer: http://run.plnkr.co/Glto1ucZyR53c99k/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6`

Answer (score 1):

The headers should be given as simple object (key value pairs) without nesting.
The object property name will become the header name and the property value will become the header value. The values should be of type string.

```js
var oHeaders = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('P1940678860' + 'rahul123')
};
```